# Origami package

Tags: documentation, draft

Does exist a specific package to draw origami?

Some example:
http://goclom.net/origami-papier/origami-grue.aspx
[image]

[image]

Comment: For *very* simple things, use TikZ. Anything not complicated and I would use a vector graphics editor and import the results with `\includegraphics`. **Edit:** unless you're looking for something that will take a list of steps and place them appropriately?

Comment: Possibly related (but much more specific): http://ctan.org/pkg/papercdcase.

Comment: Possibly related (but not actually origami): http://www.math.kit.edu/iag3/page/ka-origamis/en.

Comment: A tip for you, TreeMaker software (+its source codes), http://www.langorigami.com/science/computational/treemaker/treemaker.php. Data are saved in plain text file, but I didn't study its structure.

Comment: In general, the answer here is going to be 'no' and providing the code for anything beyond one or two examples is going to be too broad, sorry.

Comment: @SeanAllred Are there any packages that take a list of steps and place them appropriately?